# Reading Dynamic Json in hive

Tags: json, hive

I am extracting Json file everyday.The json file may vary if any new column has been added. How to read dynamic json and create the hive table syntax .How to compare the new syntax with the existing base version of hive syntax?

Regards
C

Comment: Add data samples and required results.

Comment: @Dudu just a simple json file having 3 fields on day1 . On day 2 has 4 fields.

Comment: Data samples please - including required results with emphasize on the comparison you've requested.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create /read dynamic column using json Serde .

As hive store meta only and do de serialization data (File Format
Serde Properties) at execution time.

So you have to drop and and recreate table with new column name

**Ps**.Take files backup before drooping internal table.

**Note:**It is possible with avro file format for hive 1.5 or above.